# Proving $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin^2(xy)}{x^2+y^2}=0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I tried transforming cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates, which yields $\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{\sin^2(\rho^2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta})}{\rho^2}$ but can't proceed any further. I can't find a function $g(\rho)$ such that $|f(\rho, \theta) - L| < g(\rho)$ when $\rho\to0$. I'm pretty sure this will turn out to be easy, even trivial (it's listed as one of the first exercises of my Analysis II book). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\sin t$ is asymptotic to $t$, you may consider

$$\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac1{\dfrac1{x^2}+\dfrac1{y^2}}\to0.$$

Comment: Thanks, I've actually solved this too by substituting the $sin$ factor with its 2nd order taylor expansion $\rho^2sin{\theta}cos{\theta}$ but I wasn't sure this was possible at all because the factor depends on both $\rho$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @NTAuthority: $\rho\to0$ and the $\theta$ factor is bounded.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{\sin^2(xy)}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\sin^2(xy)}{(xy)^2}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} \to 1\cdot0=0$$

indeed (by polar coordinates, as an alternative):

$$\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}=r^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta \to 0$$

or as an alternative we can also use that $x^2y^2\lt (x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: You should justify the $0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust By polar for example as an alternative.

Comment: gimusi.$x^2y^2\lt (x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2)$, $(x,y)\not=0$.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Yes it's very nice!

Comment: gimusi.Feel free to use it, if you want.Greetings.